# Adding command line argument to read all images for color palette creation

Tags: python-2.7, colors, python-imaging-library, glob

I have images in the same directory as the python file named like below.
 - cat.png
 - dog.png
 - turtle.png
 - flower.png

Currently I can run a program one at a time like below
`os.system('picol.py cat.png -s -d')`

Output:
colors_cat.png (with color palettes inside the image)

But I want to do the same thing for all the images in the directory without having to type image names one by one in the shell command.If I have 100+ images in the folder, I would have to type all 100 image names one by one which is ridiculous. It would be convenient if I can just double click on the py file (below attached) and run everything at once.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import sys
import colorgram
import argparse
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import os
from glob import glob


# The font directory is one level higher than this file.
FONT_DIR = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)),
    'fonts'
)


def get_font(fontname, size):
    try:
        font_object = ImageFont.truetype(
            os.path.join(FONT_DIR, fontname),
            size
        )
        return font_object
    except(OSError):
        print('Couldn\'t find font \'{}\''.format(fontname))
        print('Searched {}'.format(FONT_DIR))
        sys.exit()


def rgb_to_hex(value1, value2, value3):
    """
    Convert RGB color to hex color
    """
    for value in (value1, value2, value3):
        if not 0 <= value <= 255:
            raise ValueError('Value each slider must be ranges from 0 to 255')
    return {'hex_color': '#{0:02X}{1:02X}{2:02X}'.format(value1, value2,
            value3), 'link': 'http://www.color-hex.com/color/{0:02X}{1:02X}'
            '{2:02X}'.format(value1, value2, value3)}


def get_center_position_hor(canvas_height, image_in_h):
    """
    Get the correct position for an image to center it horizontally
    """
    if image_in_h < canvas_height:
        _canvas_mid = int(canvas_height / 2)
        _image_in_mid = int(image_in_h / 2)
        return _canvas_mid - _image_in_mid
    else:
        return 0


def get_center_position_ver(canvas_width, canvas_height, image_h_in):
    """
    Get the correct position for an image to center it vertically
    """
    _canvas_mid = int(canvas_height / 2)
    _image_in_mid = int(image_h_in / 2)
    return _canvas_mid - _image_in_mid


def write_out(out, filename):
    """
    Write 'out' to 'filename'
    """
    with open(filename, 'w') as fout:
        fout.write(out)


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.prog = 'piccol'
    parser.description = 'Extract the ten most used colors in an image.'
    parser.add_argument('image', action='store')
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--save-image', help='Save image to a given file',
                        action='store_true', dest='save_image')
    parser.add_argument('-d', '--do-not-show', help='Do not show the image that '
                        'is made', action='store_false', dest='do_not_show_image')
    parser.add_argument('-st', '--save-text', help='Save text to a given file',
                        action='store_true', dest='save_text')
    args = parser.parse_args()


    # Get filename of input file
    _file_name = args.image.split('/')
    file_name = _file_name[len(_file_name) - 1]

    # Extract colors from an image.
    colors = colorgram.extract(args.image, 10)

    # Make a smaller version of the received image
    image_in = Image.open(args.image)
    image_in.thumbnail((500, 500))
    image_in_w, image_in_h = image_in.size

    # Set height for canvas. This is dynamic, but has no effect until one can
    # increase/decrease the number of colors to output
    canvas_height = int(len(colors)) * 50
    # ...but if the canvas height is smaller than image_in height, set canvas
    # height to image_in height
    if canvas_height < image_in_h:
        canvas_height = image_in_h

    # Testing shows that 750px wide should be enough
    canvas_width = 750
    img = Image.new('RGB', (canvas_width, canvas_height), 'white')
    # Paste image_in into canvas and find out center position
    center_hor = get_center_position_hor(canvas_height, image_in_h)
    img.paste(image_in, (0, center_hor))
    out = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

    # Get fonts
    title_fnt = get_font('OpenSans-Light.ttf', 30)
    hex_fnt = get_font('OpenSans-LightItalic.ttf', 24)

    # Write header
    title_w, title_h = title_fnt.getsize(file_name)
    center_ver = get_center_position_ver(canvas_width, canvas_height, title_w)
    out.text((center_ver, 7), file_name, font=title_fnt, fill=(0, 0, 0))

    write_output = 'Colors for \'{}\':'.format(file_name)

    hor = 0
    ver = 120

    i = 0
    for color in colors:
        color_out = rgb_to_hex(color.rgb.r, color.rgb.g, color.rgb.b)
        if i == 0:
            pass
        else:
            hor += 50
            ver += 50
        # rectangle(())
        out.rectangle((550, hor, 600, ver), fill=color_out['hex_color'])
        out.text((610, 7 + hor), color_out['hex_color'], font=hex_fnt,
                 fill=(0, 0, 0))
        i += 1
        if args.save_text:
            write_output += '\n{} - {}'.format(color_out['hex_color'],
                                               color_out['link'])
    out_file_name = file_name.split('.')[0]
    out_file_name = 'colors_{}'.format(out_file_name)
    if args.save_text:
        out_file_name += '.txt'
        write_out(write_output, out_file_name)
    if args.save_image:
        out_file_name += '.jpg'
        img.save(out_file_name)
    if args.do_not_show_image is not False:
        img.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The python-2.7 tag of your question contradicts the shebang line at the beginning of your script which states that it's made for python3. Please check what you're looking for and maybe change the tag accordingly.

Comment: @AlexVorndran - apologies, will be careful next time to prevent any confusion. I was using python27 on windows machine but didnt recognize that line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the following code as `bulk_upload.py` in the same folder and call it like this `os.system('bulk_upload.py *.png -s -d')`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import sys
import colorgram
import argparse
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import os
import glob

# The font directory is one level higher than this file.
FONT_DIR = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)),
    'fonts'
)


def get_font(fontname, size):
    try:
        font_object = ImageFont.truetype(
            os.path.join(FONT_DIR, fontname),
            size
        )
        return font_object
    except(OSError):
        print('Couldn\'t find font \'{}\''.format(fontname))
        print('Searched {}'.format(FONT_DIR))
        sys.exit()


def rgb_to_hex(value1, value2, value3):
    """
    Convert RGB color to hex color
    """
    for value in (value1, value2, value3):
        if not 0 <= value <= 255:
            raise ValueError('Value each slider must be ranges from 0 to 255')
    return {'hex_color': '#{0:02X}{1:02X}{2:02X}'.format(value1, value2,
            value3), 'link': 'http://www.color-hex.com/color/{0:02X}{1:02X}'
            '{2:02X}'.format(value1, value2, value3)}


def get_center_position_hor(canvas_height, image_in_h):
    """
    Get the correct position for an image to center it horizontally
    """
    if image_in_h < canvas_height:
        _canvas_mid = int(canvas_height / 2)
        _image_in_mid = int(image_in_h / 2)
        return _canvas_mid - _image_in_mid
    else:
        return 0


def get_center_position_ver(canvas_width, canvas_height, image_h_in):
    """
    Get the correct position for an image to center it vertically
    """
    _canvas_mid = int(canvas_height / 2)
    _image_in_mid = int(image_h_in / 2)
    return _canvas_mid - _image_in_mid


def write_out(out, filename):
    """
    Write 'out' to 'filename'
    """
    with open(filename, 'w') as fout:
        fout.write(out)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.prog = 'piccol'
parser.description = 'Extract the ten most used colors in an image.'
parser.add_argument('image', action='store')
parser.add_argument('-s', '--save-image', help='Save image to a given file',
                        action='store_true', dest='save_image')
parser.add_argument('-d', '--do-not-show', help='Do not show the image that '
                        'is made', action='store_false', dest='do_not_show_image')
parser.add_argument('-st', '--save-text', help='Save text to a given file',
                        action='store_true', dest='save_text')

args = parser.parse_args()

def process_image(image_path):
    """
    Process each image
    """
    # Get filename of input file
    _file_name = image_path.split('/')
    file_name = _file_name[len(_file_name) - 1]

    # Extract colors from an image.
    colors = colorgram.extract(image_path, 10)

    # Make a smaller version of the received image
    image_in = Image.open(image_path)
    image_in.thumbnail((500, 500))
    image_in_w, image_in_h = image_in.size

    # Set height for canvas. This is dynamic, but has no effect until one can
    # increase/decrease the number of colors to output
    canvas_height = int(len(colors)) * 50
    # ...but if the canvas height is smaller than image_in height, set canvas
    # height to image_in height
    if canvas_height < image_in_h:
        canvas_height = image_in_h

    # Testing shows that 750px wide should be enough
    canvas_width = 750
    img = Image.new('RGB', (canvas_width, canvas_height), 'white')
    # Paste image_in into canvas and find out center position
    center_hor = get_center_position_hor(canvas_height, image_in_h)
    img.paste(image_in, (0, center_hor))
    out = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

    # Get fonts
    title_fnt = get_font('OpenSans-Light.ttf', 30)
    hex_fnt = get_font('OpenSans-LightItalic.ttf', 24)

    # Write header
    title_w, title_h = title_fnt.getsize(file_name)
    center_ver = get_center_position_ver(canvas_width, canvas_height, title_w)
    out.text((center_ver, 7), file_name, font=title_fnt, fill=(0, 0, 0))

    write_output = 'Colors for \'{}\':'.format(file_name)

    hor = 0
    ver = 120

    i = 0
    for color in colors:
        color_out = rgb_to_hex(color.rgb.r, color.rgb.g, color.rgb.b)
        if i == 0:
            pass
        else:
            hor += 50
            ver += 50
        # rectangle(())
        out.rectangle((550, hor, 600, ver), fill=color_out['hex_color'])
        out.text((610, 7 + hor), color_out['hex_color'], font=hex_fnt,
                 fill=(0, 0, 0))
        i += 1
        if args.save_text:
            write_output += '\n{} - {}'.format(color_out['hex_color'],
                                               color_out['link'])
    out_file_name = file_name.split('.')[0]
    out_file_name = 'colors_{}'.format(out_file_name)
    if args.save_text:
        out_file_name += '.txt'
        write_out(write_output, out_file_name)
    if args.save_image:
        out_file_name += '.jpg'
        img.save(out_file_name)
    if args.do_not_show_image is not False:
        img.show()

def main():
    # Allowed extensions for bulk processing
    allowed_exts = ['*.png','*.jpg']
    for i in allowed_exts:
        if str(args.image).lower().endswith(i):
            for j in sorted(glob.glob(i)):
                file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(args.image),j)
                print(file_path)
                process_image(file_path)
            break
    else:
        process_image(args.image)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

*P.S. I do not take the responsibility for any type of system break/failure*

Comment: Is there a special reason why you moved the argument parser out of the main function?

Comment: @aainaa - thank you very much for the solution and it worked like a charm in my environment on python27 windows.

Comment: @AlexVorndran YES, i want the arguments to be globally available for all the functions in the script, had i left it as is under main i would get error like `NameError: global name 'args' is not defined` from function `process_image`

Comment: @Hachi you are welcome, by the way i have tested code for both `*.png` and `*.jpg` and it works fine, you may introduce more supported extensions if you like under `main()` function